# Crawling a website with unknowing tags in between

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to crawl a data where I only know the starting and the ending tag, I have no idea about the tags there might be in between those starting and ending tags. I want to crawl all the data irrespective of the tags in between.
I am using python crawler.

Comment: Use some Python module for XML parsing. 
Read this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Comment: You said you are using python crawler - what is it? What is the module name you are using?

Comment: @alecxe - python crawler is not a module but a normal crawler that I have implemented in python [here](https://github.com/divyum/Web-Crawler/blob/master/link_crawler.py).